# Free desing при создании формы в Intelij IDEA, как в Net Beans?

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Как сделать Free desing при создании формы в Intelij IDEA, как в Net Beans?

Answer (score 0):

Я создал класс наследующий JFrame (отдельно от гуи формы), и в конструкторе прописал setLayout(null). Но сразу скажу, нужно будет писать координаты вручную, и они не везде буду выглядеть одинаково. Поэтому, если вы хотите сделать масштабное приложение, то я вам советую сделать так, как вам предлагают, и не изобретать велосипед.